# spring-boot:run multi-modular maven build

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, maven, module

I have a multi-modular maven project.

I have the root folder(parent) and the modules(childs):

- core
- ui
- rest

As of now I have to go into the rest directory to execute: mvn spring-boot:run
Then I go into UI folder and execute mvn javafx:run for the application to start.

Is there a way to do this in "one" (i.e starting the server and launching the app). Or making sure the webserver is running while executing "mvn clean install" in the parent, as that will trigger all my tests to run, and tests are failing without the server to be up and running.

Comment: I'm not massively sure why anyone would ever use the `spring-boot:run` goal in the first place to be honest. Maven is a build tool, not an application launcher. You can launch a spring boot app without Maven, obviously. Either package it into a fat jar for when you're deploying to a server, or use a run config in your IDE for when you're running locally. Having Maven as a layer of indirection to launching your app seems pointless; I'm not sure why that tutorial recommends it, other than maybe because it's platform-agnostic.

Comment: By the way, `mvn clean install` is an antipattern, [as explained by Maven's project lead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HyGxtsDf60)

Comment: @Michael the project consist of JavaFX for frontend (ui). Im still a student, and this is the requirement the teacher has set. I use mvn clean install to run all tests, spotbugs, checkstyle and jacoco. 

I need a way to start the web-server before the tests runs, and the app runs. 
In order for the app to run, I cd into UI-module and run it with: mvn javafx:run

Comment: "*this is the requirement the teacher has set*" What is? Be specific. If you can, quote them precisely. I have a hard time believing there is a requirement which is "*launch* your application with Maven". Once again, Maven is build tool. It's intended for *building* things, not as a general purpose application *launcher*.

Comment: its not written in english, but I'll directly translate:
"Maven should be used for running the application, tests and code quality"

Comment: "*I use mvn clean install to run all tests, spotbugs, checkstyle and jacoco*" If you actually watch the video, it will explain why that's not *all* that it does. You can probably get away with simply running `mvn verify`.

Comment: @Michael Yes, obviously I havent understood everything when it comes to the details of what each of the arguments does. I also use mvn verify to generate jacoco-reports, spotbugs and checkstyle and run tests. 

My point is that my teacher also have said that you should aim to build the application, run tests and start the webserver in a "one-liner" thus my question.

I'll watch the vid you linked, hopefully I get a better understanding of how maven works.

Comment: @Michael well, my tests fails due to not retrieving any information from my rest module (rest API).

Comment: The tests of which module? ui?

Comment: @Michael Yes, sorry for not being clear. Also I have to run the webserver in order for my app to work. If I do mvn clean install - > cd into ui -> mvn javafx:run (the server is not running upon doing mvn clean install phase, so I need to cd'e into rest-module and start the server, then cd back to ui and run javafx:run, then my app works).

Comment: That seems like something is wrong with your tests then. Tests in the `rest` module could perform real queries on your endpoints (e.g. with [@SpringBootTest](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)) but your UI tests should not need a running server to pass. One way to solve that is to mock the API during the UI tests (e.g. with [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/))

Comment: let me ask this one final question: if I do mvn clean install in the parent folder. After that phase is done - should I be able to make calls to my endpoints through postman for instance?